# Drupal validation for nested field element

Tags: forms

I have written some custom validation for each element in a form. I use the following method to display errors. It automatically highlights the required fields.

```
form_set_error('field_athletes_male', 'Athletes Male field is required.');
```

My problem is that there are nested element names like this:

```
 field_coaching_programme[und][0][field_organisation_delivered_by][und][0][value]
```

The validation message is shown successfully but the element is not highlighted.

Comment: From https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7 

"$name: The name of the form element. If the #parents property of your form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'."

Answer (score 1):

Its working now, code as follows

```
form_set_error('field_coaching_programme][und][0][field_organisation_delivered_by', 'Organisation delivered by field is required.');
```